# How to Compile a Test Class and Entity Framework Model.Designer.cs from CMD (Shell)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, shell, compiler-errors, cmd

I use C# and Entity Framework 4.

I'm trying to use a test Class from CMD (Shell) in Windows.

So I have my working folder containing a `Program.cs` (simple class for some tests) and the EF `Model.edmx`.

In Shell I work inside my working folder and I'm using use this code to try to `compile both Program.cs and Model.edmx`

```
csc /define:DEBUG /optimize /out:File2.exe *.cs
```

an I reciev this error:

```
Model.Designer.cs(11,19): error CS0234: The Type or name 'Objects does not exist in the namespace 'Syste.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)'
```

What I'm missing here?
Thanks guys for your help on this!

EDIT: I found an useful article here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/hu-HU/adodotnetentityframework/thread/633d1244-52dc-432c-8ad6-e908ce441988

using MSBuild.exe solved the problem but in my question i'm interested to use instead csc.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forget to reference the System.Data.Entity.dll

Might be you could try this command :

```
csc *.cs /r:System.Data.Entity.dll
```